# Wordpress Custom Post Type Permalink Structure

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I'm running a website for daily food specials with two Custom Post Types for **Restaurants** and **Specials**

In the Specials single post I use an ACF Post Object field to link the special to the restaurant that it belongs to.

The permalink of a specials post would thus look like,

```
http://localhost/foodspecials/special/2-for-1-burgers
```

The problem that arises is that more than one restaurant is likely to have the same special, which forces me to write possibly ugly permalinks.

Is it possible that the permalink would look like either of these,

```
http://localhost/foodspecials/jims-burgers/2-for-1-burgers
```

or

```
http://localhost/foodspecials/special/jims-burgers/2-for-1-burgers
```

Essentially I want to avoid having to write ugly permalinks.